# How to get .hgignore pattern to apply to subdirectories?

Tags: mercurial

I have in my .hgignore the pattern "*.pyc"

The .pyc files are indeed ignored at the root level, but not inside subdirectories.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Use `glob` syntax (put `syntax: glob` at the top of the file), and it should work. Mercurial defaults to regular expressions by default.

```
syntax: glob

*.pyc
```

Comment: What am I missing here? I create a new repository, added two .txt files, one in the root, and another inside a directory. `hg status` lists both as unknown. Then I added a .hgignore file with this line: `glob:*.txt` and now `hg status` only lists my .hgignore file. To me it seems these ignore masks already work on sub-directories. What am I missing?

Comment: wrong, ** is not required to recurse for a glob pattern. Lasse, you are not missing anything; if the expression does not contain slashes, the pattern is matched against every component of the path.

Comment: NicDumZ: Good to know. I've changed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I've tried it and I still get .pyc files appearing in my "hg st". Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 7):

By default, the patterns are python regular expressions. The expressions are searched in every component of the path. So you probably want `\.pyc$` to match files ending with .pyc

```
$ hg init test-ignore
$ cd test-ignore 
$ touch foo.pyc
$ mkdir bar 
$ touch bar/bar.pyc
$ echo "\.pyc$" > .hgignore
$ hg st        
? .hgignore
```

Note that ".pyc$" will ignore "foopyc" as the unescaped dot matches any character. Similarly ".pyc" would match "foo.pyche.bar"

If you dislike the regular expression syntax, you can switch to globals.
For instance, the current .hgignore in Mercurial's repository starts with:

```
syntax: glob

*.elc
*.orig
*.rej
*~
*.mergebackup
*.o
*.so
*.pyd
*.pyc
*.swp
*.prof
\#*\#
.\#*
```

Everything is explained in [man 5 hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html)

Comment: I've tried it with both glob and regex, and I still get .pyc files appearing in my "hg st". Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: If the file is already tracked / added to the repository, then it's not ignored. Could it be that?

Answer (score 4):

you can try to use this code

```
syntax:glob


**.pyc
```

Comment: The ** syntax is not necessary.  Just *.pyc is sufficient to traverse directories.